# pg_dumpall without prompting password

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, pg-dumpall

We are trying to automate the backup of all PostgreSQL databases of a cluster, and we decided to use 'pg_dumpall' utility. But we couldn't find a way to execute 'pg_dumpall' without prompting password. We are using PostgreSQL-10.

We are trying to execute the following command

```
pg_dumpall -U "username" -h "hostname" > "location"
```

How can we automate pg_dumpall without prompting password? Please help us on this.
Thanks

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14740/how-to-use-psql-with-no-password-prompt) on a neighboring site. There are a few ways (set environment variable, use a .pgpass file, etc)

Comment: Thanks Matt.. that worked

Answer (score 18):

I am answering my own question

we can use ".pgpass" file to avoid prompting password

" CREATING AND USING A .PGPASS FILE

=====================================

A .pgpass file will allow you to use postgres CLI tools such as psql and pg_dump without having to manually enter a password — You can use the programs from scripts without having to run them as a non password protected user.

First, create the .pgpass file

```
#nano /root/.pgpass
```

According to the official doccumentation the format of the file is as follows:

```
hostname:port:database:username:password
```

The file supports the use of # tags for comments and * to match on wildcards. Here is an example of mine:

```
*:*:*:postgres:jerry_pass
```

Enter your database information and save.

Next, set the permissions. If they are not 600 Postgres will ignore the file.

```
#chmod 600 /root/.pgpass
```

Now how do we make postgres use it? A quick scan through psql man page shows:

```
-w, --no-password
```

Never issue a password prompt. If the server requires password authentication and a password is not available by other means such as a .pgpass file, the connection attempt will fail. This option can be useful in batch jobs and scripts where no user is present to enter a password.

Here are some usage examples:

```
#psql -d postgres -U postgres -w
#pg_dump -U postgres -w -Fc   "
```